# Google Calendar Gadget Date and User Context

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am creating a simple Google Calendar gadget, the content type is html. When user clicks on the gadget icon on any particular date, I'd like to show the date as well as the first name of the user, is there anyway I can get the information in JavaScript, right inside of the gadget's HTML?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
<ModulePrefs title="Google Calendar9" />
<Require feature="google.calendar-0.5"/>
<Content type="html"><![CDATA[


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calendar Test</title>

    </head>
    <body> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // I need to get User's first name as well as the selected date 
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>

]]></Content>
</Module>
```

Thanks, 
badallen